# Header("Location...") redirects me to the same place

Tags: php, html

I hope you are doing great.
i'm using header("Location...") to redirect (traverse) from one page in my website to another apparently. The problem is that it redirects me to the same page. I checked my code and don't know where is the mistake. I wonder if you could help me with it.
Here is the useful pieces of my code.

```
<?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
            include 'Search.php';
            $url = absolute_url('Search.php');
          header("Location: $url");  
        }
        ?>
```

Thanks in advance guys. Cheers,

Comment: use `echo $url;` to check the expected url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $url; exit; // To see the value of $url
ob_start();
header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url);
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score 0):

use this one it may help you ,

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
   include 'Search.php';
   $url     =  'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/Search.php";
   header("location:$url") ;
}
```